# Apache Wicket - refreshing ListView triggered from inside the ListView

Tags: ajax, apache, listview, refresh, wicket

i got the following structure which display editable rows in an html table

```
Panel
 + WebMarkupContainer - in HTML <tbody wicket:id="container">
   + ListView which for each item in the list does (in HTML this)
     + item.add(new PopTable1Row("Pop1Panel", popTable1Item, ComponentMode.EDIT));
       + PopTable1Row component contains
         + Form
           + some inputs and a 2 submit buttons (Save, Delete)
```

Now i want to achieve that for example by clicking on delete the list view will AJAX like reload without reloading the whole page. The Delete button deletes a row from a table, so one row should disappear.

I achieved reloading the ListView by using AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior:

```
WebMarkupContainer.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)));
```

It refreshed the listView every 5 seconds.
OK, but now i want to refresh the listView in `onSubmit` of the for example the Delete Button.

And here;s the question: how to do this?

I tried in the `onSubmit`:

```
this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().render();
this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().renderComponent();
```

But both did not work.

Comment: The Buttons are Ajax Buttons? If so, they get an AjaxTarget passed in. simply add the WMC to the target and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to set outputId to true in yours listView. So Wicket will generate an id for the list tag, required to be updated by ajax.

> yourListView.setOutputMarkupId(true);

And then in your onSubmit method tell Wicket to repaint the list. Note that in the example the save button is a AjaxLink, but you can use other components.

```
AjaxLink<Void> dltBttn = new AjaxLink<Void>("yourButtonId") {
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    // your stuff

    if(target != null) {
      // tells wicket to repaint your list
      target.addComponent(yourListViewComponent); 
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Thanks also to @bert. To make this answer complete i the final code looks like this: target.addComponent(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier to inject the target component or just defining it as a member variable in your class and simply calling it by name? That way your app wouldn't break whenever you add or remove a layer...

Comment: OK not really. I have to fight something more with it.

Comment: Since the dltBttn is inside the list view, created during the populateItem() call, the list view self that it's referring to may not have been initialized.
The compeer is going to have fun with that one.